# Amcharts am4core function not defined

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I have created an interactive 2 series XY area chart for spreader beams using Amcharts, having  enqued the amchart cdn files in to Wordpress, but the chart only show in the page builder, Elementor, not on site. There is an error, am4core function not defined, and a cross origin error from amcharts, though all the sources show in chrome dev tools. Code is below, colors changed from an orginal fiddle by

https://stackoverflow.com/users/10419523/mohamed-ali-o-ameur

Url is at https://applifting.ga/modular-spreader-beams/sectionlift-6/

Any idea why this showing in Elementor but not on live site?

[image: Amcharts Elementor view]

```
let chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
    "data": [{
        "category": 0.5,
        "value1": 8,
        "value2": 6.7
    }, {
        "category": 1,
        "value1": 8,
        "value2": 6.7
    }, {
        "category": 1.5,
        "value1": 8,
        "value2": 6.7
    }, {
        "category": 2,
        "value1": 8,
        "value2": 6.7
    }, {
        "category": 2.5,
        "value1": 8,
        "value2": 5
    }, {
        "category": 3,
        "value1": 6.5,
        "value2": 3.7
    }, {
        "category": 3.5,
        "value1": 5,
        "value2": 2.9
    }, {
        "category": 4,
        "value1": 3.9,
        "value2": 2.3
    }],
    "xAxes": [{
        "type": "CategoryAxis",
        "id": "id-1",
        "title": {
            "type": "Label",
            "id": "span",
            "text": "Span in Metres"
        },
        "dataFields": {
            "category": "category"
        },
        "startLocation": 0.5,
        "endLocation": 0.5,
        "renderer": {
            "grid": {
                "template": {
                    "type": "Grid",
                    "location": 0.5
                }
            },
            "minGridDistance": 20
        }
    }],
    "yAxes": [{
        "type": "ValueAxis",
        "id": "id-2",
        "title": {
            "type": "Label",
            "id": "swl",
            "text": "S.W.L in Tonnes",
            "propertyFields": {}
        },
        "min": "0",
        "max": "10",
        "renderer": {
            "maxLabelPosition": 0.98
        }
    }],
    "series": [{
        "type": "LineSeries",
        "name": "30° Sling To Vertical Angle",
        "xAxis": "id-1",
        "yAxis": "id-2",
        "baseAxis": "id-1",
        "dataFields": {
            "valueY": "value1",
            "categoryX": "category"
        },
        "fillOpacity": 0.5,
        "strokeWidth": 2,
        "sequencedInterpolation": true,
        "sequencedInterpolationDelay": 100,
        "tooltipText": "{name}\n{categoryX}: {valueY}"
    }, {
        "type": "LineSeries",
        "name": "45° Sling To Vertical Angle",
        "xAxis": "id-1",
        "yAxis": "id-2",
        "dataFields": {
            "valueY": "value2",
            "categoryX": "category"
        },
        "simplifiedProcessing": true,
        "calculatePercent": true,
        "fillOpacity": 0.5,
        "strokeWidth": 2,
        "sequencedInterpolation": true,
        "sequencedInterpolationDelay": 100,
        "tooltipText": "{name}\n{categoryX}: {valueY}"
    }],
    "legend": {
        "type": "Legend",
        "setStateOnChildren": true,
        "showOnInit": true,
        "visible": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "dataFields": {},
        "position": "top"
    },
    "cursor": {
        "type": "XYCursor",
        "tooltipPosition": "fixed"
    },
    "dataFields": {},
    "colors": {
        "type": "ColorSet",
        "wrap": false,
        "shuffle": false,
        "reuse": false,
        "baseColor": "#567876"
    }


}, "$CHART$", am4charts.XYChart);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inject the scripts IN THE HEADER with this code:

```
function admin_style() {
?>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'admin_style');
```

Please check this live example
https://jsfiddle.net/gxhqefbt/

Comment: No this not work at all, it is blank now in Elementor ,was better before? Must only be  minor problem somewhere, as the scripts are showing, and chart works fine in Elementor, is same url, should show, red/pink chart

Comment: I would not consider Elementor are a reference for this, that builder has tons of js and other files it needs to run the builder so the frontend result is the important part here.

Comment: Indeed, but the scripts are showing as registered, there is an error Uncaught ReferenceError: am4core is not defined
    <anonymous> https://applifting.ga/modular-spreader-beams/sectionlift-6/:611  other way the scripts don't register

Comment: Sir, they need to be in the HEADER not in the footer! in JS, the source file must be inserted before the function.

Comment: That chart should show on page, but function is undefined

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer: don't use "admin_enqueue_scripts" it will only enqueue the scripts the back end, us 'wp_head' instead.

Comment: Yes they must be going in footer that is why function undefined,

Comment: Yes i just used headers footer plugin, but thats what it was, am just posting another final question, how to get "tonnes" and "metres" after the digits in tooltips? Thanks